# Base object as argument to function which takes derived object

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, arguments

I want to write a function which takes as an argument an object from the class "Armor", however, when I call the function, I use instead an object from the base class "Item". Of course this object I use, even though may only be considered an "Item", may also be an "Armor". Only when I am sure it is an "Armor", I want to call the function.

In my case, I store items in a vector (these items can be armors). I want to get this item from the vector and call the function with it (equip the item, which I know is an armor).

```
class Item{
};

class Armor : public Item{
};

void equipArmor(Armor armor){ //Armor class argument
    //Equip the armor

}

int main(){
    vector<Item> items;
    Armor a;
    items.push_back(a);

    equipArmor(items[0]); //Call function with an "Item" as an argument (even though it is in fact also an "Armor")
}
```

Comment: You might want to look up static and dynamic casts.

Comment: Or before that, inheritance?

Comment: You haven't shown the inheritance relationship in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

You have a vector of `Item`.  When you `push_back` an `Armor` it will be [sliced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) into an `Item`.  So in the vector you have no longer an `Armor` but just an ordinary `Item`.

This is why your code won't work.  First you cannot call your `equipArmor()` function with an `Item`, since it expects an `Armor` and downcasting is never implicit.   But even if you could, you would always pass an `Item` value and never an `Armor` value.

#### The solution

To solve your issue, you need to work with pointers (better smart pointers) or references.

The first thing you will need to be able to work with [polymorphic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic) types and doing runtime type determination, is to have at least one virtual function in your base class:

```
class Item{
public: 
    virtual ~Item() {} 
};
```

Now let's make your vector a vector of [shared pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/).  The nice thing is that those will ensure that objects will be destroyed when they are no longer used in any shared pointer.  So less hassle with memory management, and less hassle with the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) :

```
vector<shared_ptr<Item>> items;

shared_ptr<Item> a = make_shared<Armor>();
items.push_back(a);
shared_ptr<Item> i = make_shared<Item>();
items.push_back(i);

equipArmor(items[0]); // lets just try the two possible cases
equipArmor(items[1]);
```

Finally,  in your function, you can then sense for the real type and act accordingly, in a **safe** manner using [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/):

```
void equipArmor(shared_ptr<Item> item){ //Armor class argument
    shared_ptr<Armor> a = dynamic_pointer_cast<Armor>(item);  
    if (a) {
        cout << "Armor"<<endl; 
    }
    else cout << "Item"<<endl;     
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/4H7oO5)

**Remarks**

If your type is not polymorphic, you cannot you `dynamic_pointer_cast`.  You still could cast with a [`static_pointer_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/static_pointer_cast/), but this is risky, because it requires you to know for sure that the casted smart pointer has the right type.

If you prefer raw pointers,  you the same principles would apply, but yo'ud use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) or `static_cast` respectively.  But again,  [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) requires you to be absolutely sure of the type.  And how can you be, if you have a vector full of random items ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to cast from the base class (`Item`) to the subclass (`Armor`). This is impossible.

You could do this if `items` would be a vector of pointers to `Item`s. You can then cast an `Item *` to an `Armor *` if you are sure that the underlying object is actually an `Armour`.

```
int main(){
    std::vector<Item *> items;
    Armor a;
    items.push_back(&a);

    // This only works if items[0] points to an Armor object
    equipArmor(*static_cast<Armor *>(items[0]));
}
```